# How to update only one model in a database-first approach?

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller

I have a model generated from a db with .NET Core. When I have any change in database, I update model from database to get the change in model. But this update is applied to all entities (tables) included in model.

I want to update a specific table in .NET Core, not all if change in more than one table, I have searched about it, but have not found any command or way for it.

Comment: This question is too broad. Simple google search will result in a lot guides on how to use entity framework.

Comment: Make changes progressively, one by one, as needed

Answer (score 0):

3 ideas :

1. Scaffold your DB in a specific Directory and pickup only what you want

   > ef dbcontext scaffold "cnx-string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir=ModelTMP
2. Scaffold your DB in another blank project and pickup only what you want
3. You should consider **code first approach** with for example a dedicate project for that :
   a simple project dedicate (class library) to your MODEL
   a simple project dedicate (console app) to manage migration

With this approach, you could :

- Manage several DBContext and then different DB exposure
- Play with the (intermediate) migration file